# Defaulting an environment variable in a makefile

Tags: bash, makefile

I have a makefile in which I want some default behavior that can be changed via an ENV var.

This works fine:

```
foo:
    echo "${MY_VAR}
```

However when a try to add the default, things stop working:

```
foo:
    echo "${MY_VAR:-defaultValue}"
```

This always echo's an empty string. If I execute the echo directly on my shell it works as expected, and I get either the value of MY_VAR, or defaultValue, depending on if MY_VAR was set.

I remember having problems in Makefiles before. Do they have some "special bash rules"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no special bash rules.

However, there is a big difference between *make* variables and *shell* variables.

Make variables (set in the makefile) are referenced by `$(FOO)` or `${FOO}`.  Make variables don't support shell composing operations like `:-`.

Shell variables are `$FOO` or `${FOO}`, but because that syntax overlaps with make's variable syntax you have to *escape* them so that make doesn't mess with them.  You do that by doubling the `$`, so to access a shell variable from within a makefile recipe you write `$$FOO` or `$${FOO}`.

You haven't made clear in your example whether `MY_VAR` is a *make* variable or a *shell* variable so we can't give you a solution.

Comment: MY_VAR is a shell variable. `MY_VAR=foo; export MY_VAR`. Escaping worked: `echo "$${MY_VAR:-defaultValue}"`